# Where is macOS's "main log" from Console.app stored?

Tags: macos, console.app

Console.app in macOS shows the "main log" in Devices > My Mac, plus various "reports". For these reports, I can right-click and say "Show in Finder" to go to the actual log file location. For the main log, however, there seems to be no such option.

Is the main log also stored somewhere on disk?

Comment: https://kb.scandimension.com/view-system-logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

macOS uses "Unified Logging" which collects logging from multiple sources. Understanding and using the Unified Log is complex. The data is stored in multiple folders located at `/private/var/db/diagnostics`. Think of this as a complex database, not as a log file.

The `log` command gives you access to this data and allows you to extract just the information you need and, if you want, to extract data to a **logarchive** for more permanent storage.

Some links to further information:

- [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) Developer Documentation - very much aimed a developers.
- [Mandiant](https://www.mandiant.com/resources/blog/reviewing-macos-unified-logs) for a more approachable description and how to use the Unified Log.
- [Eclectic Light](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/03/19/macos-unified-log-1-why-what-and-how/) is the first of many blog posts from Howard Oakley - search his web site for more.

Apart from the `log` command, the only apps I have used to access logs are those from Howard Oakley. See [Log Utilities](https://eclecticlight.co/consolation-t2m2-and-log-utilities/). His app, Consolation is perhaps of the most used of these. Time Machine Mechanic is an excellent example of an app focused on one particular aspect of macOS.